# How to make total of cart price in a shopping cart?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have created a sample shopping cart that stores the data in `localStorage` and display it in the cart. The problem where I am stuck is the total of prices as it's kept on concatenating all the price values but not doing the SUM of it. Suppose, two items have prices `100$` & `600$` respectively then the total amount is coming as `100600`.

How can I solve this problem?

HTML code:

```html
<div class="total"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
const cTotal = cartbox.querySelector('.total');
let cartTotal = '';
let price = '';

JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items")).map(data=>
{
    price = data.price;
    for(var i = 0; i < price.length; i++)
    {
        cartTotal += price[i];
    }
});
cartTotal = '<p class="amount">Total Amount: '+cartTotal+'</p>'

cTotal.innerHTML = cartTotal;
```

Comment: Seems like you need to separate a price and a currency, and store a price as a `number`.

Comment: In localStorage, the price is stored as a number, While displaying it.. I just have added a $ sign but I am fetching the prices in total from the localStorage i.e. int only

Comment: Hi @jaspreet Singh , try initializing cartTotal and price like
let cartTotal = 0;
let price ';
you initialize it as string that's why its concatenating rather than sum

Comment: Hello @priyankaGiri, I tried your method but still got similar result except a 0 got added infront of the value like this -> 0100600

Comment: If you get a result like "0100600" then your `price[i]` is a `string` but not a `number`.

Comment: @sergdenisov That can be the possibility, Do you know a way where I can parse the price as a int?

Comment: You can try `parseInt(price[i], 10)` for example, but it's better to store as a `number` in `localStorage`. It would be better if you could show your data JSON.

Comment: @sergdenisov  I used unary operator to convert string data to int and it finally worked. Now, the only problem I am currently facing is that to multiply it with quantity... I tried doing price = price + (data.price * data.no) (no is quantity) Then the total gets 0. any suggestions for this?

Comment: Create a working code snippet so we could debug it.

Comment: `let cartTotal = '';` <-- empty string WHY?

Comment: I admit, my bad.. That would be an int variable instead of string.. thanks to you guys, I made it work except some minor things anyways thanks again

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
let cartTotal = 0;
```

```
price = data.price;

for(var i = 0; i < price.length; i++)
{
  cartTotal += parseFloat(price[i]);
}
```

---

Full code:

```
HTML CODE: 
<div class="total"></div>


JavaScript:
 const cTotal = cartbox.querySelector('.total');
 let cartTotal = 0;
 let price = 0;

  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items")).map(data=>
  {
      price = data.price;
      for(var i = 0; i < price.length; i++)
      {
            cartTotal += parseFloat(price[i]);
       }
   });
    cartTotal = '<p class="amount">Total Amount: '+cartTotal+'</p>'
           
    cTotal.innerHTML = cartTotal;
```

Comment: Using this -> cartTotal += Number.parseFloat(price[i]); is returning only two digit numbers of the value. Suppose, my price total is 1400 then it is returning 14. Any solutions without adding * 100 because it just mess the calculation?

Comment: Can you paste your `localStorage.getItem("items")` ?

Answer (score 1):

First off, in order to avoid [type coersion](https://medium.com/developers-arena/type-coercion-in-javascript-c973b369b272), change this line

```
let cartTotal = '';
```

to this:

```
let cartTotal = 0;
```

Next, to *force* type coersion on the other end, change this line:

```
cartTotal += price[i];
```

to this:

```
cartTotal += Number.parseInt(price[i]);
```

or to [support floats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseFloat):

```
cartTotal += Number.parseFloat(price[i]);
```

Comment: Using this -> cartTotal += Number.parseInt(price[i]); is returning only two digit numbers of the value. Suppose, my price total is 1400 then it is returning 14. Any solutions without adding * 100 because it just mess the calculation?

Comment: You'll probably find that the raw values you're getting from localStorage are wrong. I recommend working with cents, and converting to dollars only at display time.

Answer (score 1):

all you need is to add `parseInt` to make sure that your price is in **number** format
besides that change your initial value of `cartTotal` to `0` like this

```
 const cTotal = cartbox.querySelector('.total');
 const parsedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items")); 
 let cartTotal = 0;

 parsedData.map(data => {
      for(var i = 0; i < data.price.length; i++)
      {
          cartTotal += parseInt(data.price[i]);
      }
 });

 cartTotal = '<p class="amount">Total Amount: '+cartTotal+'</p>'          
 cTotal.innerHTML = cartTotal;
```

> Note: if the prices may have numbers after the period use `parseFloat` instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    price = data.price;
    cartTotal = price.reduce(function(a,b){
            return a+b;
          });
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: price.reduce is not a function

However, I used unary operator to convert string data to int as it was saved as a string in localStorage.. The only problem I am currently facing is that to multiply it with quantity...

I tried doing price = price + (data.price * data.no) (no is quantity) 

Then the total gets 0. any suggestions for this?

Comment: Can You show the data input for this script?

Comment: It's a bit long code but here's a glimpse

       addtocart[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
            if(typeof(Storage) !== 'undefined')
            {
                let item = {
                    id:i+1,
                    name:e.target.parentElement.children[2].textContent,
                    price:e.target.parentElement.children[1].textContent,
                    no:1,
                };

Comment: if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) === null)
                {
                    items.push(item);
                    localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(items));

                    window.location.reload();
                }

Comment: data.price is not an array. That's one of your problems